# Why does DBMS_UTILITY.COMPILE_SCHEMA break function-based indexes?

Tags: oracle

After mass structure updates, some views/procedures became invalid.

So I just recompiled them with:

```
exec dbms_utility.compile_schema( USER )
```

But after that, all function-based indexes, which before were in a good state, became broken, and SQL statements against those tables failed. And that is the problem.

Example of such indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX DOCUMENTS_NMBR_UCN_FIDX ON DOCUMENTS(Str2Number(NUMBER_UCN));

CREATE INDEX DOCUMENTS_DATE_FIDX ON DOCUMENTS(Date2Number(REG_DATE));
```

Why did that happen?

Comment: You should only recompile invalid objects. Otherwise Oracle thinks your function's body has changed. And then how is Oracle supposed to know that your function `Str2Number` doesn't all of a sudden return different values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oracle is compiling *all* objects, so as far as Oracle is concerned all code in all objects is new code.

As a consequence, Oracle has no way of knowing that your function `Str2Number` still returns the same values that were used when the index was created.

Instead you should only recompile invalid objects,

```
exec dbms_utility.compile_schema(user, false);
```

will do this.

Comment: this really helps. thanx.
but it is unfair from oracle
1. befor compile_schema indexes was ok and than become broken
2. if it recompiles ALL objects, why it skips function-based indexes 
3. no warnings about ...  just screams from end-point users :(

Comment: An index isn't a compiled object like a stored procedure. You (re)build an index, not (re)compile it.

Comment: I do also wonder if TO_NUMBER has been overlooked

Comment: Possibly, but in general for a user-defined function used in a function-based index the above holds.

Comment: Seems like a good reason to try to avoid using user-defined functions in function-based indexes if they can be avoided. Str2Number doesn't sound like it brings much to the party that to_number wouldn't.

Comment: Good point. And don't forget that more complex expressions (of built-in functions) can also be used in a function-based index -- it doesn't have to be a single function call.